# Containing div doesn't fully expand to contain children with percent

Tags: css

I have a div that expands to fit its children divs but when I give the children padding or margins specified in percent, the parent doesn't seem to account for that space. However if I specify the padding or margins using pixels it works fine which seems odd. I've been searching for a solution but to no avail. I've tried this in both Firefox and Chrome which are the only browsers I have to support.
http://jsfiddle.net/YTsmz/5/

With pixels:
[image: example with pixels]

With Percent:
[image]

The html:

```
<div class="field">
    <div class="name">countries</div>
    <div class="value">united states</div>
    <div class="value">united kingdom</div>
    <div class="value">dominican republic</div>
</div>
```

The css:

```
.field {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    border-right: 1px dotted #3d3d3d;
    line-height: 1em;
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding: 0 1% 0 1%;
    font-weight:bold;
}
.field .name {
    font-size:1em;
    line-height:1.5em;
}
.field .value {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0% 1% 0% 0%;
    border-right: 1px dotted #3d3d3d;
    padding: 0 1% 0 1%;
    font-size:1.3em;
    line-height:1.3em;
}
.field .value:last-of-type {
    border-right: none;
}
```

Comment: It's because padding: 0 1% 0 1%; is calculated in relation with parent width.